# OAuth 2 Design Explanation

Tags: oauth-2.0

I need a recommendation for a learning resource (book, video, etc.) that can explain with details the rationale of OAuth 2.0 design.

I know how the design works, but I would like to get clarifications of why some steps or parameters are necessary and what kind of vulnerabilities would come up if they weren’t there.

For example, why do we need refresh tokens, why can’t the last access token serve as the refresh token?

Please do not point me to the RFC, I have read it.

Answer (score 1):

OAuth is an authorization framework. It is all about the access token, and the business permissions it conveys. OAuth also has a very strong focus on separation of concerns.

To answer your question about refresh tokens, the concerns of a short lived message credential and another one that renews it are separated. They may have different security requirements in some use cases.

For example, a refresh token might contain a reference to a database record containing a delegation, with details related to consent and expiry. This information is not relevant to access tokens.

Also, token refresh is only available to clients, who should provide a client credential when possible. Rogue APIs should not be able to refresh their own access tokens. It is hard to reason about all such threats and best to follow standards vetted by many experts.

At Curity, where I work, we produced this [consumer friendly OAuth overview](https://curity.io/resources/learn/oauth-overview/) a while back. It is intended to provide the type of rationale you are requesting. It is a pure standards based article.